# How to implement file download with AJAX and MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I would like to provide a file download operation by using the jQuery AJAX call with some params under MVC

Example

```
(javascript)
function DoDownload(startDate) {

  $.ajax({ 
     url:"controller/GetFile/",
     data: {startDate:startDate}
     ...
  });

}

C# Controller Code

 public void GetFile(string startDate) {

  var results = doQueryWith(startDate);

   // Create file based on results
   ....
   // How do I tell the server to make this a file download??
 }
```

I typically would just make my file download a link such as:

```
<a h r e f="mycontroller/getfile/1"/>Download</a>
```

but in the case above the date will be dynamic.

If I don't use ajax, what would be a preferred way to pass in the params to the MVC controller using javascript?

Example:

```
window.location  = "mycontroller/GetFile/" + $("#fromDate").val();
```

assuming the date is 12-25-2012

Would this produce

```
mycontroller/GetFile/12/25/2012
```

would MVC treat this as three params?

Comment: The answer to your question can be found at [this][1] link.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-mvc/5830215#5830215

Comment: Unless you need a "hackable" URL, I am not sure you need to do it this way. Just pass the date as a parameter to a controller method and then use the suggested FileResult implementation. You may be making this harder than it needs to be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What I ended up doing is calling my controller from my javascript like:

```
var url = "/mycontroller/GetFile?startDate=" + $("#mydate").val() + etc...

window.location = url;
```

mycontroller.cs

```
 public void GetFile(DateTime startDate) 
{

}
```

My original concern was with the date parameters. I didnt want to have to parse it.

Comment: One more comment, despite of the different dates in the world it's very accepted now everywhere to use ISO-8601 instead of any other format. Unfortunately MVC wraps dates in a weird way and it's not exactly the most popular one. I suggest you always to use ISO-8601 because you can change your controller in the future in an easier way.

Comment: This works perfectly for downloading a file where a jQuery Ajax call does not. Thank you for this terse yet elegant solution!

Answer (score 4):

Using the ActionLink helper, you can pass multiple params to your controller:

```
HtmlHelper.ActionLink(
    string linkText, 
    string actionName, 
    string controllerName, 
    object routeValues, 
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

So in your case:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download file", "GetFile", "MyController", new { startDate = "##" }, new { id="mydownloadlink" })
```

Using jQuery you can change the value of the `startDate` in the link with the content of your date picker or textbox.

```
$("#mydownloadlink").attr("href").replace("##", $("#yourdatetexbox").val);
```

Then, in your controller, just use one of the other answers here, about `FileResult`.

Hope this help you...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470835%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) method of controller class to return a file back to the browser.

The below sample returns a pdf file.

```
public ActionResult GetFile(int id)
{
  var fileInfo=repositary.GetFileDedetails(id);
  var byteArrayOFFile=fileInfo.FileContentAsByteArray();
  return File(byteArrayOFFile,"application/pdf","yourFriendlyName.pdf");
}
```

Assuming `repositary.GetFileDedetails` method returns the details of the file from the id.

You may also return the file from a physical location(a path) or a stream. Check all the [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) of the `File` method and use appropriate one.

*This has nothing to do with ajax. this is normal `GET` request over a browser.*

Answer (score 1):

Your controller action method should return a FileResult instead of void.  And there is no need to do this via  AJAX - in fact, you don't want to do this with AJAX.  You'll need the browser involved so it knows to provide a download dialog for the user.

See these links:

[Handling an ASP.NET MVC FileResult returned in an (jQuery) Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028623/handeling-an-asp-net-mvc-fileresult-returned-in-an-jquery-ajax-call)

[File download in Asp.Net MVC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597179/file-download-in-asp-net-mvc-2)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am really stuck on how to pass the params to MVC controller. Or what is the best way.

Comment: Romias' answer below shows how to pass values to your action method using the ActionLink.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Make sure you return a File from your controller action with contentType as "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" and file name as e.g. "List.xlsx" which should be the same as in the AJAX success call. I have used ClosedXML NuGet package to generate the excel file.

```
public IActionResult GetFile(DateTime startDate)
    {
        var results = doQueryWith(startDate);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Grid");
        //populate dt here.
        //if you result is a data table you can assign it to dt
        dt = results;
        string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        string fileName = "List.xlsx";

        using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            workbook.Worksheets.Add(dt);

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                workbook.SaveAs(stream);
                workbook.SaveAs(stream);
                var content = stream.ToArray();
                return File(content, contentType, fileName);
            }
        }
    }

//.cshtml (JQuery AJAX call to the controller action)
$.ajax({
    url:"ControllerName/GetFile/",
    data: {startDate:startDate}     
    contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    xhrFields: { responseType: 'blob' },
    success: function (data) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = 'List.xlsx';
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }
});
```