# Download File with Jquery Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using jquery Ajax for downloading PDF file, I generate PDF on runtime and download it, 
This is my Ajax call

```
  $.ajax({
            async: "false",
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Reports/DownloadFile?userId=" + encodeURIComponent(userId) + "&date=" + encodeURIComponent(date),
            success: function (result) {
            }
        });
```

and this is what I am doing in ActionResult

```
 public FileContentResult DownloadFile(int userId, string date, int rptType)
        {
            var userInfo = UserBLL.GetUserByID(associateId).Name;
            var dtFileDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
            var pdfStream = GeneratePDFStream(userId, date);//Generating Stream

if(date < DateTime.Now)
{       
return File(pdfStream, "application/pdf", string.Format("MyReport{0}{1}.pdf", userInfo.Name, dtFileDate.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "")));
}
return null; 
        }
```

but its returning

```
Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.
```

How can I download the file with Ajax call? Please note that I can't use jquery FileDownload but I can do without Ajax call, Kindly suggest
I also tried with this,but same error

```
 var url = "/Reports/DownloadFile?userId=" + encodeURIComponent(userId) + "&date=" + encodeURIComponent(date);

        window.open(url);
```

Comment: You should try opening the pdf data-url or blob url in an iframe on the page

Comment: or return url of PDF, and open it in new window like, window.open("UrlOfFile.pdf")

Comment: Can you show some sample code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement file download with AJAX and MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087743/how-to-implement-file-download-with-ajax-and-mvc)

Comment: so...many...duplicates......

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ajax call, just try using `Iframe` as(demo code) :

```
var url = "/Reports/DownloadFile?userId=" + encodeURIComponent(userId) + "&date=" + encodeURIComponent(date) ;

var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
             .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + url + '" width="850px" height="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>')
              .dialog({
                  autoOpen: false,
                  modal: true,
                  height: 625,
                  width: 850,
                  title: 'YourPdfFile'
              });
        $dialog.dialog('open');
```

Comment: let me try,will it download the file?

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi..the above code will show toolbar also and there is a option for print in that toolbar..